# re.findall possible variable names

Tags: python

I created list called identifiers in which I want to put, loading from .txt file, all possible "identifiers" which can name a variable. For example (c4, a123 etc.)

```
lexicalClass = file.readlines()


for lex in lexicalClass:
    newList = re.findall('\S+', lex)
    for element in newList:
        if len(re.findall('[a-z]+|[0-9]+', element)):
            identifiers.extend(re.findall('[a-z]+|[0-9]+', element))
```

.txt file :

```
a273 = 4 + 1337
for i in range 50:aifj++
variable = 50.123132123 + 3.123123132 / 23.121212
```

but in my identifiers list, I also get numbers splitted with . , but I only want in identifiers list strings which can name variable

i tried with

```
![^0-9.]
```

but then all strings with numbers are not counted

Answer (score 1):

If you're certain that variables in the text file can only be lowercase letters followed by digits I suggest that you remove the "or" `|` so that the regexp becomes

```
[a-b]+[0-9]+
```

The `|` makes it match any sequence consisting only of lowecase letters or digits.

Comment: The generic regex for matching any valid Python identifier (ignoring Unicode characters) is `[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*`.